# antd drawer disable shadow

Tags: reactjs, antd

im trying to disable a shadow in the `Drawer` from `antd` components, what im trying to disable is the shadow, i already disable the mask but i cant find way to disable the shadow, here is the shadow

[image]

i already tried `BoxShadow` inside the `maskStyle` and i cant find any solutions to this probles

Comment: ```.ant-drawer-right.ant-drawer-open .ant-drawer-content-wrapper {box-shadow: none}```

Comment: can you explain more ? do i need to put that code or find it inside the antd package ?

Comment: This is css to hide right side drawer. Just put it into your component css.

Comment: ok thats work, can you post it as an answer so i can accept it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this css to hide drawer box-shadow:

```
.ant-drawer-right.ant-drawer-open .ant-drawer-content-wrapper {
  box-shadow: none
}
```

Comment: Better to wrap this class in some custom class so this style don't affect globally

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this option in the `Drawer` component:

```
contentWrapperStyle={{ boxShadow: 'none' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.ant-table .ant-table-container::before,
.ant-table .ant-table-container::after {
  width: 0px !important;
}
```